# Meta privileges help page inconsistency

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, reputation, help-center

There appears to be an inconsistency on our [Meta privileges page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) in the Help Center!

The unflappable dev [Chris Jester-Young](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3/chris-jester-young) and our benevolent overlords in the SE Community Team have lowered PPCG's meta participation privilege reputation threshold to 1. Excellent news! That means that new users can post to the sandbox and ask questions about the site on Meta.

The problem is now that the privileges page does not consistently reflect this. At the top it says that the privilege is awarded at 1 rep, but at the bottom of the page it explains why 5 rep is required. That's rather misleading.

Could someone please look into this?

Comment: Unflappable!​​​

Comment: From the updated page: *Why do I need 1 rep to post there?* Umm... yea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A 5 has been changed into a 1.

That is all.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! "Why do I need 1 rep to post here?" seems a little odd, but it's consistent.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't want to remove the whole section - it has some important information. But... by all means, if you have better phrasing or want that to be different, it can be changed.

Comment: It's not a big deal and I can't think of anything better anyway but I appreciate your willingness to facilitate further changes. Thanks again!

Comment: It is still a little misleading, that new users may think there is a distinction between having 1 rep and no rep at all.